# Can't set the `Account` property in Mail rule

Tags: mail.app, catalina, gmail

When I set my personal account as the `Account` property, close the dialog, and edit the rule again, the `Account` property is set back to iCloud.

I suspect this has something to do with my Gmail account since this happens only when I try to set my personal Gmail account as the `Account` property.

I have tried setting other accounts as the `Account` property and they seem to be saved correctly; two of them are Gmail Enterprise accounts except for one that is a regular free tier one.
[image]
I would like to know what to look for here. Maybe I've hit some quota on my personal account, maybe there's some configuration I'm missing.

Comment: What’s the “account” icloud field? Maybe it overrides the from? Why not just set the filter on gmails end? That’s how I personally manage my gmail filters.

Comment: @JBallin I made a horrible mistake, I meant `Account` instead of `From`

Comment: @MarioGil did you ever figure out how to address this issue in Mail?  I've just started using Mail and am having the exact same problem!